# incrementing a multidimensional numpy array (python) with products generated from a set of vectors corresponding to axes of the array

Tags: python, numpy

A is a k dimensional numpy array of floats (k could be pretty big,  e.g. up to 10)

I need to implement an update to A by incrementing each of the values (as described below). I'm wondering if there is a numpy-style way that would be fast.

Let `L_i` be the length of `axis i`

An update to this array is generated in two steps follows:

1. For each axis of A  a corresponding vector G is generated. 
   For example, corresponding to axis i a vector G_i of length L_i is generated (from data).
2. Update A at all positions by calculating an increment from the G vectors for each position in A

To do this at any particular position,  let p be an array of k indices,  corresponding to a position in A. Then A at p is incremented by a value calculated as the product:

```
Product(G_i[p[i]], for i from 0 to k-1)
```

A full update to A involves doing this operation for all locations in A  (i.e. all possible values of p)

This operation would be very slow doing positions one by one via loops.

Is there a numpy style way to do this that would be fast?

edit

```
##  this for three dimensions, final matrix at pos i,j,k has the 
## product of c[i]*b[j]*a[k]
## but for arbitrary # of dimensions it will have a loop in a loop 
## and will be slow
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4,5])
c = np.array([6,7,8,9])

ab = []
for bval in b:
    ab.append(bval*a)
ab = np.stack(ab)

abc = []
for cval in c:
    abc.append(cval*ab)
abc = np.stack(abc)
```

as a function

```
def loopfunc(arraylist):
    ndim = len(arraylist)
    m = arraylist[0]
    for i in range(1,ndim):
        ml = []
        for val in arraylist[i]:
            ml.append(val*m)
        m = np.stack(ml)
    return m
```

Comment: The description is hard to follow. Could you provide a code example for A shape (3, 4), i.e., k=2?

Comment: for k=2 it is just the dot product of the two vectors e.g. a vector of length L_i times a vector of length L_j to yield a matrix of dim L_i,L_j  .   Call this matrix x.  Now if we have a third vector c of length L_k,  the product I'm talking about will consist of a new array of dim  L_i,L_j, L_k .  The first element of this array is a copy of x  with all of the values multiple by the first element of c.  The second element of this 3D array is a copy of x with all of the values multiplied by the second element of c.   etc etc   Hope that helps

Comment: Please, show a couple of lines of code how you would manually handle this for a small array, otherwise we'll be going back and forth with misunderstandings about what you want.

Comment: I added a code segment to the original post

Answer (score 2):

This is a wacky problem, but I like it.

If I understand what you need from your example, you can accomplish this with some reshaping trickery and NumPy's usual broadcasting rules. The idea is to reshape each array so it has the right number of dimensions, then just directly multiply.

Here's a function that implements this.

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

def wacky_outer_product(*arrays):
    assert len(arrays) >= 2
    assert all(arr.ndim == 1 for arr in arrays)
    ndim = len(arrays)
    shapes = scipy.linalg.toeplitz((-1,) + (1,) * (ndim - 1))
    reshaped = (arr.reshape(new_shape) for arr, new_shape in zip(arrays, shapes))
    return reduce(operator.mul, reshaped).T
```

Testing this on your example arrays, we have:

```py
>>> foo = wacky_outer_product(a, b, c)
>>> np.all(foo, abc)
True
```

#### Edit

Ok, the above function is fun, but the below is probably much better. No transposing, clearer, and *much* smaller:

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator
import numpy as np

def wacky_outer_product(*arrays):
    return reduce(operator.mul, np.ix_(*reversed(arrays)))
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'd not have thought of that.   I did some timings and it looks like wacky_outer_product() consistently takes about 60% of the time as does a function version of my code (added to original comment)

Comment: @J.Hey Bueno! I did basic timing tests, but sort of hard to tell without larger inputs. Seems faster, not enormously so.

Comment: elegant, but that takes about 4 times as long as original wacky_outer_product()

Comment: @J.Hey The second version? By my timing it's about 2x faster. Again, small inputs though, YMMV.

Comment: Note: because cache memory is sensitive to how the data is arranged and accessed in memory, the order of the multiplications matters. In the second ("clearer and smaller") implementation, changing the expression to `reduce(operator.mul, reversed(np.ix_(*reversed(arrays))))` was a factor 2 faster (on a, b, c sizes 100, 101, 102). Which surprised me, because the original order, with a final multiplication step of shapes (102, 101, 1) and (1, 1, 100) looks much more cache-friendly to me than (102, 1, 1) * (1, 101, 100).